# sqoop how to handle deletion/updation of records in HDFS

Tags: mysql, hadoop, sqoop

I have a requirement to import data from a RDBMS to HDFS using sqoop on every day. The records are partitioned in HDFS on a column  DeptID and also partitioned to Hive. There is a possibility of new records get added and also some records are deleted from the source database on every day. I understand sqoop merge can handle updates. We always want the state of the files in the HDFS is same as that of database records, i.e if records deleted/updated  in the database the same should be deleted/updated in the HDFS.  Let me put a small example.

1. On day1 records from 1 to 100 are moved to HDFS.
2. On day2 new records 101 to 150 are added and 10 to 30 are removed in the database.
3. Now the HDFS should contain the partitions with records of 1 to 10, 31-150 records.(10 - 30 records should be removed from HDFS).

I would like to know is it possible with the current behavior of sqoop, or a custom map-reduce is required to accomplish this.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your table is not too big, the best thing you can do through sqoop is a full import every day, overwriting the previous state. Removing deleted data is an hard task to be accomplished, since you don't know which of them are deleted...

Answer (score 0):

This is not impossible. I have implemented the same scenarios using Sqoop and pig scripts. You get your data incrementally everyday using sqoop.

if some data is deleted at source, the source should send some flag for those records. This can be implemented on the source side.

Once you get the records with flag you can write a pig/hive (I prefer pig) for filtering out those records from the data that you have in hdfs.

Please read about SCD Type 2(Slowly Changing Dimensions ) in the following link :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

This should clear all your doubts.

Snapshot load from sqoop is also an option but it doesn't help if your data is huge in size.

Hope this helps

Comment: u mean flag here, a new column to identify within same table or a new table

Comment: it may be a new flag column in the same table or a new table with the deleted records.